spring boot bootBuildImage hangs in minikube docker context
I have a spring boot 3.2.5 application and want to deploy it on minikube v1.33.0.
According to the documentation I need to set the environment variables for windows with:
& minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression

This will then set the environment variables so the docker command connects to the docker engine of minikube.
However in order to get a local image on that docker environment I need to build it again using
./gradlew bootBuildimage

This works fine in the normal docker environment but once I set the minikube version It just hangs:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :demo:bootBuildImage
Building image 'docker.io/library/demo:latest'

<===========--> 85% EXECUTING [5m 39s]
> :demo:bootBuildImage

Not sure if relevant but the demo spring boot app is a subproject in gradle.
I consulted How to run a Spring Boot application in Minikube?
So another option would be that I push it to a repository (probably docker hub) and fetch the image from there. However I would like to understand what I might be doing wrong with my first approach.

It seems I needed to be patient as the first time takes a long time.
Using --debug I saw a lot of activity (but kept spewing out a lot of hex codes) after half an hour I just stopped it and relaunched it with --info and I saw it restored some progress and after a couple of minutes it was done.

The first time you run ./gradlew bootBuildimage it might take a while to pull the necessary builder and run images. You should see Gradle log messages containing like Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest' and Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base. This might take a minute or two on a reasonably fast computer and network connection. Half an hour is a really long time. How long does it take if you do docker pull docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest?
